Boostrap Nav Tabs using anchor links to show tab
Currently using bootstrap 5.0 (just straight html/css) and am having trouble figuring how to get an anchor link to open up a tab.
<div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home">
    CONTENT FOR HOME
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="onboard">
    <a href="#build" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#build">Show Build tab</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="build">
    CONTENT FOR HOME
  </div>
</div>


<ul class="info-navigation" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Start</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-onboard-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#onboard" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-onboard" aria-selected="false">1</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-build-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#build" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-build" aria-selected="false">2</button>
  </li>
</ul>


Just want to be able to add anchor links or buttons within the tab panels itself that would open up the next/targeted tab.
Tried using the data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#build" but didn't really work.

Please tag your Bootstrap version. FYI, Bootstrap 5.0 is very old. Update if you can. Many bugfixes and new features have been added since 2021.

You can leverage Bootstrap's JavaScript API. By adding an event listener to the link and using the Tab.show() method, you can switch to the tab where you need
Reference Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navs-tabs/#methods


    document.getElementById('openBuildTab').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var buildTab = new bootstrap.Tab(document.getElementById('pills-build-tab'));
        buildTab.show();
    });
<div class="container mt-5">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="pills-onboard-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#onboard" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-onboard" aria-selected="false">Onboard</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="pills-build-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#build" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-build" aria-selected="false">Build</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
            CONTENT FOR HOME
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="onboard" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-onboard-tab">
            <a href="#" id="openBuildTab">Show Build tab</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="build" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-build-tab">
            CONTENT FOR BUILD
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



